# JavaFX: TableView not showing up in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview, fxml

I am attempting to bind my program to the GUI designed in SceneBuilder.
I have managed to get my 'Accounts.class' ID's displayed as wanted in the far left list.

Now I need to get the TableView working but I am having no luck getting it to populate with data.

It should contain data from the fields of 'Invoice.class',
Inside each Account object there is an Set - this set will be displayed on different rows in the right TableView.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

p.s. forgive me I know it has been asked many times before but all the other solutions seem to not work for me I have tried adding the type in the parameter like;

```
  tableAccount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Invoice, Account>("id"));
```

Having no luck with this getting really frustrated. I have messed around since last night with no improvements at all so posting here was my last resort.

**Controller.class**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{
    final ObservableList<Account> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Account("A", "B"));
    @FXML
    private TableView<?> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tableAccount;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tableDate;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tableTime;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tableTotal;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tableNotes;
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> list;
    @FXML
    private TextArea invoiceView;
    @FXML
    private TextField amountField;
    @FXML
    private Button addAmount;
    @FXML
    private Button newInvoice;
    @FXML
    private Button saveInvoice;
    @FXML
    private Button deleteInvoice;
    @FXML
    private Label messageBar;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //list.setPlaceholder(new Label("No Content In List"));

        setAccountsList();
        //tableView = new TableView<>(names);
        Account ac1 = new Account("A-02", "Tina", "96 Grove Vale", "London", "N1 8PT");
        Invoice inv = ac1.newInvoice();
        InvoiceCalculator calc = new InvoiceCalculator();
        inv.add(4.50);
        inv.add(4.50);
        inv.add(3.00);
        inv.add(15.00);
        calc.calculateInvoice(inv);

        setTableView(ac1);


    }

    private void setTableView(Account a) {
        tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableAccount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        tableDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        tableTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("time"));
        tableTotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("total"));
        tableNotes.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("notes"));

        //tableView.setItems(setTableAccounts());
    }

    @FXML
    public void listViewSelected() {
        list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
       // newInvoice.setText(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    }

    @FXML
    public void newInvoiceFired() {
        System.out.println("new invoice button has been clicked");
    }

    @FXML
    public void deleteInvoiceFired() {
        System.out.println("delete invoice button has been clicked");

    }
    @FXML
    public void saveInvoiceFired() {
        System.out.println("save invoice button has been clicked");

    }

    public void setAccountsList(){
        ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        names.addAll(Main.getAllAccounts().stream().map(Account::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        list.setItems(names);
        names.add("T-112");
    }

    public ObservableList<Account> setTableAccounts(){
        ObservableList<Account> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        names.addAll(Main.getAllAccounts());
        return names;
    }

}
```

**Account.class**

```
public class Account {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String postCode;
    private Set<Invoice> invoiceArchive = new HashSet<>();

    public Account(String id, String name, String address1, String address2, String postCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.postCode = postCode;
        Main.addAccount(this);
    }

    public Account(String id, String name, String address1, String postCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    public Account(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getPostCode() {
        return postCode;
    }

    public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    public Set<Invoice> getInvoiceArchive() {
        return invoiceArchive;
    }

    public Invoice newInvoice(){
        Invoice i = new Invoice(this);
        invoiceArchive.add(i);
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getId();
    }
}
```

**Invoice.class**

```
public class Invoice {
    private Account id;
    private ArrayList<Double> invoiceAmounts;
    private double invoiceTotal;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String notes;
    private String modified;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");



    public Invoice(Account id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.invoiceAmounts = new ArrayList<>();
        this.date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setModified(String date) {
        this.modified = date;
    }

    public Account getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Account id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getInvoiceAmounts() {
        return invoiceAmounts;
    }

    public void setInvoiceAmounts(ArrayList<Double> invoiceAmounts) {
        this.invoiceAmounts = invoiceAmounts;
    }

    public double getInvoiceTotal() {
        return invoiceTotal;
    }

    public void setInvoiceTotal(double invoiceTotal) {
        this.invoiceTotal = invoiceTotal;
    }

    public void add(Double d){
        invoiceAmounts.add(d);
    }

    private String returnInvoiceAmounts(){
        String result="";
        for (Double d:invoiceAmounts){
            result += "£"+df.format(d)+"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Account: "+id.getId()+
                "\nCreated: "+getDate()+"\n"+returnInvoiceAmounts()
                +"--------"+"\nTotal\n£"+df.format(invoiceTotal);
    }
}
```

**GUI.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="641.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.24249999999999972" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="427.0" prefWidth="641.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <ListView fx:id="list" layoutX="-24.0" layoutY="62.0" onKeyPressed="#listViewSelected" onKeyReleased="#listViewSelected" onMouseClicked="#listViewSelected" prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="151.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="411.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.30023640661938533" layoutX="143.0" layoutY="123.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="480.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <TableView layoutX="128.0" layoutY="45.0" prefHeight="208.0" prefWidth="478.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                <columns>
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="tableAccount" prefWidth="75.0" text="Account" />
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableDate" prefWidth="75.0" text="Date" />
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="tableTime" prefWidth="75.0" text="Time" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="tableTotal" prefWidth="75.0" text="Amount" />
                                    <TableColumn fx:id="tableNotes" prefWidth="75.0" text="Notes" />
                                </columns>
                              </TableView>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="286.0" prefWidth="478.0">
                           <children>
                              <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4474789915966387" layoutX="168.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="292.0" prefWidth="478.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                <items>
                                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <children>
                                          <TextArea fx:id="invoiceView" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="290.0" prefWidth="209.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                       </children>
                                    </AnchorPane>
                                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <children>
                                          <TextField fx:id="amountField" layoutX="82.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="104.0" promptText="0.00" />
                                          <Button fx:id="addAmount" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="86.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" />
                                          <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="91.0" text="Amount: : " />
                                       </children>
                                    </AnchorPane>
                                </items>
                              </SplitPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="11.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Icon/Logo.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="462.0" layoutY="14.0" spacing="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="newInvoice" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newInvoiceFired" text="New" />
            <Button fx:id="saveInvoice" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteInvoiceFired" text="Save" />
            <Button fx:id="deleteInvoice" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteInvoiceFired" text="Delete" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[** GUI Display **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72enr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue, after spending a ages trying to solve it.

It seems that it was trivial, in GUI.fxml I did not assign an ID to tableView therefor it was never being initialised in the controller and I was receiving a NullPointerException when setting it

```
TableView fx:id="tableView"
```

I am so mad at myself for wasting so much time but this is my first experience with fxml and javafx so learnt a lot.

Comment: @James_D thanks for your guidance, i just had to dig deeper to realise where the null pointer started.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the correct types for your fields. Since each row in the table is a `Invoice`, you should have a `TableView<Invoice>`. Since the `tableAccount` column displays properties of type `Account` from an object of type `Invoice`, it should be `TableColumn<Invoice, Account>`, etc. `tableDate`, I'm assuming (since `date` is a `String`) displays properties of type `String` from `Invoice`, so it should be a `TableColumn<Invoice, String>`. And so on,. Then you will be able to set the cell value factory, using either a `PropertyValueFactory` (with matching types) as you show, or (probably better) just using a lambda (i.e. `tableAccount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getId()));`).

Second, don't create a new table! (You have already been told this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781355/javafx-listview-not-displaying-in-gui).) Your table is defined in the FXML file, and the table that is defined there is displayed in the UI. In your `setTableView` method you create a new table, and configure it. But since that table is never shown in the UI, you will never see the result of the configuration. Don't create a new table, just configure the one you already have.

Finally, it's not really clear how you are trying to populate the table. You say every row in the table is an invoice: so that means that `table.setItems(...)` will expect an `ObservableList<Invoice>`. You are trying to give it an `ObservableList<Account>`. You need to generate the appropriate list of invoices here (you haven't specified what that should be) instead of a list of `Account`s.

There may be other errors here, but those are the most obvious (to me), and should get you on the right track.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed reply. I have realised this now I thought maybe this is just showing me that they are generic. I have changed as advised and will check shorty. Ill sort out the ObservableList aswell will report back soon :)

Comment: I have adjusted the `setTableView(Account)` method to include all the lambdas and call the `setItems(Account)` method, it is now as follows `ObservableList<Invoice> invoices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        a.getInvoiceArchive().forEach(c -> invoices.add(c));`. It is now throwing a NullPointerException for the following `at Controller.setTableView
 at Controller.initialize`. I have passed through the account from `initialize(a)` to `setTableView(a)` to `setTableAccounts(a)` not sure why and if its setTableAccounts returning null - I have initialised 1 invoice for that account.

Comment: What is actually null?

Comment: I have run a `println(invoices)` which prints the data as expected so I am not sure why I am getting this. It is definitely the `setTableAccounts()` method that is causing this exception - could it be that         `tableView.setItems(setTableAccounts(a))` is not the right syntax for this?

Comment: Is that line throwing the exception? If so, then `tableView` is obviously null. Why would you think it had anything to do with `setTableAccounts`?

Comment: but I am using the `setItems()` method on 'tableView' to populate it, at least thats what I was aiming to do.

Comment: Don't post the stack trace in comments; it is unreadable. Just say which line in your code is throwing the exception and identify what is null.