# (JavaFX) How come my ListView is empty even though the string I'm adding to it is not empty?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a ListView that can be saved to a text file. The text file is successfully populated but when I try to read from the text file to fill the ListView, nothing appears. Furthermore, to make sure that the text file isn't empty, I print its contents to the console which shows up perfectly. Why aren't the strings appearing in the ListView? Thanks.

```
    if (event.getSource() == accept0) {
        stage0.close();
        DirectoryChooser chooser1 = new DirectoryChooser();
        chooser1.setTitle("Select Folder");
        File dir1 = chooser1.showDialog(null);
        String line;

        if (dir1.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir1.getAbsoluteFile() + "\\ListViewItems.txt"));

                if (!br1.ready()) {
                    br1.close();
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                    items.getItems().add(line); //adding line from text file to ListView
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                br1.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Declaration and initialization of the `ListView` and `ObservableList`

```
private ObservableList<String> item = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ListView<String> items = new ListView<String>(item);
```

Comment: There's a couple different things that can be happening, it's hard to tell because your code isn't complete, you don't even include where you define your ListView! Try putting in a breakpoint, or print statements, to see what `items.getItems()` actually contains. I suspect it has the right Strings in it, but they aren't being shown in the ListView properly, which may require you to fiddle with its CellFactory.

Comment: @MMAdams The ListView is a field of the class its in. I changed that the println statement to print `items.getItems().get(0)` and it actually successfully printed what was being read from the file. How would I go about adjusting the CellFactory so that it would show? Thanks.

Comment: I take back the CellFactory thing, with Strings you shouldn't need one. There could be other reasons for your ListView to display as empty though, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781355/javafx-listview-not-displaying-in-gui where the ListView being displayed by the FXML and the ListView being changed programatically were different Objects.

Comment: @MMAdams I'm not using FXML so I don't think there's an issue with that. I'm going to have too keep playing with the code to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Show your `ListView` and `ObservableList` declaration and initialization.

Comment: Actually, you should start here -> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should be adding the data to your `ObservableList `. `ListView` basics [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm).

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Every time I'd add an item to the ListView I'd do so by calling `items.getItems.add("something")` and `"something"` would successfully appear in the list. I haven't actually put anything into the ObservableList.

Comment: Follow the `ListView` tutorial I linked. Also, rename your variables. That may be causing you confusion.